# How exactly docker loads code from my local with docker run command?

Tags: angular, docker, nginx

I have recently joined a project. For that Project we are using using **Nginx** on top of **docker** to run **Angular** project locally.

I have found below script which runs my project on localhost :

`docker run -p 80:80 --name nginx projectName:nginx`

I want to know how exactly docker know about **location of my project on local machine at the time of run** and how it loads code for the same.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`peojectName:nginx` is a docker image which this runs. A docker image is a file comprising of many layers. A user builds a docker image to include the code, system libraries and any other files required in the image. So when you build the image you send a `build context` to the docker daemon which is the entire contents of the folder you built the image from.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate docker image of your application, your dist folder(this folder path given in docker file to copy) of angular application will be moved to Docker daemon or say in docker context but when you run the docker it will host your image including your application dist folder and then a separate container created where application actually run.